# js add property to url param object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url that I create the following way:

```
let forwardBaseUrl = 'https://www.usergems.com/api/gmail/info?' + $.params({
                event: 'Click forwarded link',
                email: btoa(userEmail),
                properties: {
                    forwardId: btoa(forwardId)
                }
            });
```

Is there an easy way to later add a property to the properties object:
I want the same result as this:

```
let forwardBaseUrl = 'https://www.usergems.com/api/gmail/info?' + $.params({
                event: 'Click forwarded link',
                email: btoa(userEmail),
                properties: {
                    forwardId: btoa(forwardId),
                    forwardUrl: 'http://google.at'
                }
            });
```

best would be a solution that merges the params. Similar to this (obviously not working):

```
forwardBaseUrl.params.push({properties: { forwardUrl }})
```

Comment: forwardBaseUrl+="&forwardUrl="+"http://google.at"

Answer (score 2):

First, the actual JQuery method is **[`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)**, not `$.params()`.

Next, if you refactor your code to "build" the "params" object and set up a function that can add a property to your object, then you can regenerate the serialized result anytime you like:

```js
var userEmail = "me@you.com";
var forwardId = "12345";

var props = {
    forwardId: btoa(forwardId)
};

var paramObj = {
  event: 'Click forwarded link',
  email: btoa(userEmail),
  properties: props
};

let forwardBaseUrl = 'https://www.usergems.com/api/gmail/info?' + $.param(paramObj);

console.log(forwardBaseUrl);

function changeProperties(prop, value, addRemove){
    if(addRemove){
      // Add new property to properties object
      props[prop] = value;
    } else {
      // remove property from properties object
      delete props[prop];
    }
}

// Add a new property to the params "properties" object:
changeProperties("forwardUrl", "http://google.at", true);

// Update serialized params
forwardBaseUrl = 'https://www.usergems.com/api/gmail/info?' + $.param(paramObj);

console.log(forwardBaseUrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var restObj = {
  url: 'https://www.usergems.com/api/gmail/info?'
  params: {
     event: 'Click forwarded link',
     email: 'asda',
     properties: {
        forwardId: btoa('asd')
     }
  },
  getUrl: function () {
    return this.url + $.param(this.params);
  }
}
```

// now you can change params object
restObj.params.properties.anotherParam = 'param';

// and get new url
console.log(restObjgetUrl.)